# Azure Firewall - no rule allows to access external FQDN but telnet connects to it

Tags: azure, firewall

I have a subnet with Route table with the only route `0.0.0.0/0 => AzureFirewallIP` in it.
Azure firewall does not have rules allowing access to external resources. But still I can `telnet some.domain.com 443` and get connected!

WTF?

When I issue `curl -k ...` though, I get *Encountered end of file*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Azure engineers this is by design and this has no security impact at all.